# How to make Sqlite work for Android with Unity and SQLiteUnityKit

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

To make a Unity app for Android, I need to use SQL, and it looks like SQLite is well supported on every platform. Despite this, I'm having the following issue:

I am using [SQLiteUnityKit](https://github.com/Busta117/SQLiteUnityKit), and it looks like a lot of people have been using this framework for building SQL app.

Here is the code I tried to make it work from the [Doc](http://bravenewmethod.com/2015/04/11/quickstart-sqlite-unity/):

```
public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
SqliteDatabase sqlDB;

public Text Firstname;

void Awake() 
{
    string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "game.db");
    var dbTemplatePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "default.db");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath)) {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            WWW reader = new WWW(dbTemplatePath);
            while ( !reader.isDone) {}
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dbPath, reader.bytes);
        } else {
            System.IO.File.Copy(dbTemplatePath, dbPath, true);
        }
    }
    sqlDB = new SqliteDatabase(dbPath);
    //Insert
    string query = "insert into person values('B', 'David')";
    sqlDB.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
    query = "insert into person values('B', 'Alex')";
    sqlDB.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
    //Query
    var result = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
    var row = result.Rows[1];
    Debug.Log("lastname=" + (string)row["lastname"]);
    Debug.Log("firstname=" + (string)row["firstname"]);
    Firstname.text = (string)row ["firstname"];
}
}
```

The problem is that basically this code works fine when I launch the project as you can see:

[image]

But in my Android Emulator:

[image]

There is never a name coming. It just stays with "my lastname" which is nothing more than a placeholder.

EDIT: I just tested to build the project for a mac application and it runs without a problem.